# How do I turn off automatic downloads and updates?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I don't see any options for deactivating automatic downloads for OS X and individual apps in the App Store app.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable automatic updates for individual apps.

The only options are to have automatic updates, or to not have automatic updates. It is not possible for granular control currently. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score -1):

## System Preferences → App Store → uncheck options

[image: System Preferences]
[image: App Store prefs]

Comment: The question states 'individual apps'? Are you simply looking to disable them completely? If so, this question is a duplicate.